# Force image download jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have been working with the code below to force images to download. Yes I'm aware of the html5 attribute but it does not work for all browsers. My problem seems to be with the execute the actual button that calls the function

```
    function SaveToDisk(fileURL, fileName) {
        // for non-IE
        if (!window.ActiveXObject) {
            var save = document.createElement('a');
            save.href = fileURL;
            save.target = '_blank';
            save.download = fileName || 'unknown';

            var event = document.createEvent('Event');
            event.initEvent('click', true, true);
            save.dispatchEvent(event);
            (window.URL || window.webkitURL).revokeObjectURL(save.href);
        }

        // for IE
        else if ( !! window.ActiveXObject && document.execCommand)     {
            var _window = window.open(fileURL, '_blank');
            _window.document.close();
            _window.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, fileName || fileURL)
            _window.close();
        }

    // IE 11 
   try {
        var evt = new MouseEvent('click'); } catch (e) {
        window.open(fileURL, fileName); 
} 
}
```

just a test image it will be a photo.jpg when done.

```
<button style="width: 100px; height: 50px;" onclick=SaveToDisk(<?php echo $imagelarge[0]; ?>http://lorempixel.com/400/200/);></button>
```

Comment: What does jQuery have to do here?

Answer (score 0):

`onclick` attribute syntax is wrong. Its value must be enclosed in double or single qoutes and contain valid javascript code.

```
<button style="width: 100px; height: 50px;" onclick="SaveToDisk('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/', 'fileName.jpg')">Download</button>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/57Lvaghy/1/) full working example.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.